# Prevent TypeScript compiler exiting batch script

Tags: typescript, batch-file

I have a file called **run.bat** which is supposed to compile a TypeScript file and then run the outputted JavaScript file in Node.js:

```
tsc
node index.js
```

The problem is that the TypeScript compiler exits the batch script after it has finished compiling, so the command `node index.js` never gets executed.

**How can I ensure that the commands after `tsc` get executed?**

I have tried looking at the [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html), but was unable to find any options to stop the TypeScript compiler exiting the batch script.

Comment: `tsc` is a `.bat` or  `.cmd`? -> `call tsc`

Comment: @Stephan Replacing `tsc` with `call tsc` worked. Thanks for your help. Please post it as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Windows, `tsc` is a batch file. By default, when you call a batch file from a batch file, it never comes back.

To call it and have control return to your batch file when done, use `call`:

```
call tsc
node index.js
```

---

If you're curious, here's what the `tsc.bat` file looks like:

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL
CALL :find_dp0

IF EXIST "%dp0%\node.exe" (
  SET "_prog=%dp0%\node.exe"
) ELSE (
  SET "_prog=node"
  SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
)

"%_prog%"  "%dp0%\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc" %*
ENDLOCAL
EXIT /b %errorlevel%
:find_dp0
SET dp0=%~dp0
EXIT /b
```

Comment: Maybe a better way is `call tsc.bat` with full file and extension.

Comment: @Gerhard - Why? Then if they change it to a `.cmd` file at some point in the future, the script breaks. Leaving off the extension is standard practice when calling Windows batch files.

Comment: create a file in the same dir where `tsc.bat` exists and name it `tsc.exe` then run `call tsc` and see what happens.

Comment: Well, actually, I should not say change the answer, it might be worth mentioning though..

Comment: Wow, I actually just realized how badly this `tsc.bat` file was written, does the file originate from `npm`?